# Is there a way to reorder reddit posts? or make a couple always stay at the top?

Tags: reddit

I'm a moderator on a reddit and am really liking it.

The issue I have is that I would like to have a couple posts shown above the new ones

Comment: In essence you're looking to pin things to the top?

Comment: yes, that is what I'm trying to do

Comment: Do you know how to edit the CSS? That's about the only way

Answer (score 2):

Use the "mod shield" button under the post to open the menu, and select "Sticky post". You can have up to two posts pinned to the top of a subreddit at the same time. If you want to direct people to more posts than that, you could pin a single post that links to other posts.

[image: toolbar under a post showing mod shield icon and its options]

[Image source](https://www.reddit.com/r/modhelp/comments/b70yf2/how_to_sticky_a_post_at_the_top_of_a_subreddit_on/): jippiejee

Example sticky post (note the pin icon in the corner):

[image: post at top of subreddit showing green pin in the corner]

See also the [official docs for sticky posts](https://support.reddithelp.com/hc/en-us/articles/15484641176724-Sticky-posts)